# How can I show prototype UITableViewCells in a UITableView without a UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UITableView` with a prototype `UITableViewCell` all being controlled by a `UIViewController` but when I run the app, the `UITableViewCell` doesn't show. How can I make this show?

If you're wondering why, I want to have [this layout](http://prntscr.com/k40h43), which I can't achieve with a `UITableViewController`.

Also, I'm to to iOS development as of yesterday, so sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: You can make an `IBOutlet` to the table view and make the view controller the delegate, then implement the required delegate methods. While I’m not familiar with it, you might be able to put a `UITableViewController` within a container view.

Comment: you need to read a tutorial on how to use `UITableView` in `Swift`

Comment: @Chris I created an `IBOutlet` to the table view but I can't set the delegate to my view controller because the delegate variable is of type `UITableView` and the view controller is of type LocationsViewController (which extends UIViewController).

Comment: @Kamran I've looked at how to use `UITableView` in `Swift` but all of them require a `UITableViewController`.

Comment: You need to drag from the `delegate` and `datasource` outlets in Interface Builder to your view controller. Your view controller needs to implement `UITableViewDelegate` and most importantly `UITableViewDataSource` functions. Try this http://www.thomashanning.com/uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners/

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you very much, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved, I looked at a proper tutorial on how to make a table view.